# AWS Credentials File Multiple Roles Same Profile

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, credentials

If I want to have in my `.aws/credentials` file access keys for one AWS profile / account ID but want individual credentials listed for each role-name associated with that account ID and profile combo (`arn:aws:iam::account-id:role/role-name` - i.e want to be able to refer to the credentials for profile X, account Y for roles A, B and C and have the AWS credentials SDK be able to read it properly or commands like `terraform init` use the credentials properly). Is that possible?

I did some digging and wasn't able to see much. One solution is that if I wanted to reference Profile X, account Y and role A then I'd update my credentials to that corresponding ARN and then edit the `.aws/credentials` file and only be able to have on type of role for profile X and account Y at a time. I wasn't able to find something where I could have multiple role credentials for one profile X/account Y combo. For example the below doesn't seem possible:

```
#.aws/credentials file
[X-A]
aws_access_key_id = keyid_roleA
aws_secret_access_key = key_roleA
aws_session_token = token_roleA

[X-B]
aws_access_key_id = keyid_roleB
aws_secret_access_key = key_roleB
aws_session_token = token_roleB

[X-C]
aws_access_key_id = keyid_roleC
aws_secret_access_key = key_roleC
aws_session_token = token_roleC
```

Comment: You can use named profile for this. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html

Comment: There's no explicit notion of 'account' here. It's just a profile name and an associated set of credentials. Yes, you can configure multiple profiles, with different profile names. Feel free to create whatever naming convention works for you as a profile name, such as x-a, x-b, etc.

Comment: Thanks @ChetanRanpariya and @jarmod but when I set up named profiles in `.aws/config` example I now have `[profile X-A]` and `[profile-B]` listed and have correspondingly labeled the profiles in my `.aws/credentials` file as such with their appropriate specific role-name ARNs (both within profile X though) but it doesn't seem to properly communicate with AWS credentials SDK / running a command like `terraform init` after refreshing these credentials doesn't properly apply the credentials to profile X

Comment: Aws profiles on Machine use only acceskeyid and secret. The roles associated with that user will be applied when performing any aws operation with that profile. There is no way to use a specific role for a profile at runtime.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya ok thanks so if I'm trying to do this during runtime then I can only have one specific role under that one profile at a time? Is that a correct assumption? And if I want to use credentials for that same profile but for another role then I just have to edit the `.aws/credentials` files and delete the credentials in there for the previous role and repopulate with credentials for the new role? And thus I cannot have credentials for 2 different roles for one profile at the same time?

Comment: One user can have a role associated with it. So when that user tries to perform action in aws, it will be allowed or not allowed based on the permissions configured in the role. So you can not apply a different role to a user when performing action. You Need to change the user's current role to also have those permissions of different role or you use a different user which has that role associated with it.

Comment: Aws client profiles are used for having multiple users configured on same client. And you can choose which profile to use when performing aws operation. You don't need to remove credentials from file. You just need to use different profile from the file. I hope I am able to make things clear.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya yes this has been helpful! Appreciate your time and patience as I'm new to this. I see - are you saying if I have an account ID 123 associated with two roles, role A and role B. Then when I refresh AWS credentials for account 123 for profile X, then these credentials are updated for both roles? Thus, credentials are dependent on account ID / profile and not on roles? (ie same credentials are used for role A and role B? for every profile X / account ID combo?). And when I actually execute the action, I just need to switch roles when executing the actions themselves?

Comment: @hhprogram I am not sure I am getting what problem you are trying to solve. I think you are can get more understanding about how AWS IAM works by reading [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/introduction.html)

Comment: Thanks @ChetanRanpariya I've looked at that already but I'll give it another look. The problem / misunderstanding I'm trying to solve is - I have one account ID and I want to refresh credentials for it and store credentials for that account ID for role A and role B and both in the `.aws/credentials` file for some profile X. But I'm seeing that if I have that then commands like `terraform init` do not know which credentials to use or if I name it [profileX-roleA] it throws an error as in aws profileX is just named profileX. Maybe I'm misunderstanding AWS, but that's how I can describe it now